# Creating an explicit unsafe private class member access function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

TypeScript allows access of instance properties and methods which have been declared `private instanceProperty` but not explicitly `#instanceProperty`.

However, it still typechecks this access, eg

```ts
class SomeClass {
  private __someProperty: string;

  notPrivate: number;

  constructor() {
    this.__someProperty = "foo";
    this.notPrivate = 7;
  }
}

const instance = new SomeClass();

console.log(instance.notPrivate); // 7
console.log(instance.__someProperty); // compile error
// Property '__someProperty' is private and only accessible within class 'SomeClass'.

console.log(instance["notPrivate"]); // 7
console.log(instance["__someProperty"]); // "foo"
console.log(instance["nonExistentProp"]); // compile error w/ noImplicitAny
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
// '"nonExistentProp"' can't be used to index type 'SomeClass '.
//   Property 'nonExistentProp' does not exist on type 'SomeClass '.
```

Because of this, I was experimenting with creating an explicit mechanism for exposing private properties. I started here:

```ts
export function unsafe_expose<Instance, InstanceProperty extends keyof Instance>(
  instance: Instance,
  property: InstanceProperty,
) {
  return instance as unknown as Omit<Instance, InstanceProperty> & {
    [key in InstanceProperty]: Instance[InstanceProperty];
  };
}
```

however, when trying to use this function, I get an error:

```ts
const unprivate = unsafe_expose(instance, "__someProperty");
// Argument of type '"__someProperty"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof SomeClass'.
```

This leads me to the understanding that the type constraint for `Type["key"]` is broader than `keyof Type`, and I'm curious if there's access to that broader constraint within the TypeScript type system somehow.

This was mostly a thought experiment and has no intent for production code at the moment, so I'll take "Tl;Dr no it's not possible" as a valid response.

Comment: Note that you will want to [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) the private property since an intersection of a private property and a public one is still going to be inaccessible (see [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0Vdaw)).  Please [edit] the question to use `Omit` this way so that the answer can focus on your actual problem and not this aside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible to use [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) to enumerate [`private` class members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private).  There are various feature requests asking for things that would enable this, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#22677](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22677) and [microsoft/TypeScript#46802](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46802).  For now it's not part of the language.

However, you *can* still use [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to look up the types of such members.  So you can write your function like this:

```
function unsafe_expose<T, K extends PropertyKey>(
  instance: T,
  property: K,
) {
  return instance as unknown as Omit<T, K> & {
    [P in K]: (T & { [k: PropertyKey]: unknown })[K];
  };
}
```

Note that since `K` cannot be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `keyof T`, then `T[K]` will yield an error (but still evaluate to the right type).  In order to avoid that error without using something drastic like [the `//@ts-ignore` directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments)), we can index into `T & {[k: PropertyKey]: unknown}`, since that will allow indexing with every possible key, and result in `T[K] & unknown` which is equivalent to `T[K]`.

This gives you the behavior you want:

```
const unprivate = unsafe_expose(instance, "__someProperty");
/* const unprivate: Omit<SomeClass, "__someProperty"> & {
    __someProperty: string;
} */

unprivate.__someProperty; // string
```

But it also allows you to access nonexistent properties:

```
const oops = unsafe_expose(instance, "oopsie");
/* const oops: Omit<SomeClass, "oopsie"> & {
    oopsie: unknown;
} */
```

The type [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) is a reasonable type here, since it doesn't let you do much (and `T[K]` when `K` is not known to be a key of `T` is correctly given the `unknown` type).  There might be some clever [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to prevent accessing truly nonexistent properties, but that seems to be mostly out of scope for a function whose point is to break through abstraction barriers.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFaBvAsAKGmgAcAnASwDcwAXZaAfXoiWQAUT4jkTqBPALmgRq5AHYBzANz58hUfGrtKNZINEBXRACNu0vLOjB4o4SXXBq8EgAoAlNgOFqACzIQAdI2Yp2nbn2gAXmgAIgAzeHgQvUInVw95RXIqWiDoAHYY6ABffFz9PCMTamgyYrBRYDpg0WQAdzgWdEgIOz18IuYQZHcQeHFrMuEKqvdEpRTkW0loAHpZjI7jLp6+gaHqEZ6vFl8uHl5puYWjRCIybuhuDhJ8eeg9-15oAHJGHZ8Ofb4X0phSZSpCoAE2gxhAzzAwCqUDIWkudTILjKhgwMBeCBQzSgL3cMkKy3g3V6-UG5UqyAA2iFxskVCEALpHe7pJYmImrUkbLbUj5sL5PRnMhbhSIhNkrEnrclVanyUQAUQAHm5aKIkpwhTN7qdzpdrlZoHUFvIAJJnEBkYBIgCCol4dwWCu6KHVpQtVqREOgzkg0AqrwqvF+fC40B0wDA6ggdGQStIyFhxjBYWgoeQjteNOMytVyHVexCv0joheJR00GjyFBllKomBcbTvDDGKaaNeeLw90IjwOr3lueE+Y1RF+wPgiegiSuKuEYNETZbmLQ7dx+LjRCsJTC6kq1DIyd3EDAYWQ9A38BjAB4ACoAGmgAGkZ2rgTBe3xH8heAA+awGbkKUEe8DFIPwDkER873wexcAIaASGQah1BIBdAKqf0YF3ABreQ6gXP0AHlECRW8H0fH9oAAMgceDCEpVg6yfBlBGsG9qOwaBKWwwQP14L9eBYytRFw+B8JyWxKUfBksmyPR8nxToSl3AFJjSI8TzPC8YzJYYKQfEI+T4kJpjuAAqQxlmU0RVJUQRiNI5dsQgAyjIFA4Qkomi4NiBgmF2dy+EEUwyikPJoDM2Z8RUulaE8fzPnAvhtQWEKJEUqywU4GBgg009z3jS9kF0zZ9NCSIiAgMhkBMvRZgspSssq+ySOoK8nLRAyKqqmqvNo3zuuqwQcLw0R5IiqK8CAA)